# How to group a list by multiple values in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I have this list:

```
List<MoveItem> _items = [
MoveItem(
  shelf: A01,
  itemName: 'Dumpling',
  quantity: 3,
  expiryDate: DateTime(2021, 12, 8),   
),
MoveItem(
  shelf: A02,
  itemName: 'Dumpling',
  quantity: 3,
  expiryDate: DateTime(2021, 12, 8),     
),
MoveItem(
  shelf: A03
  itemName: 'Dumpling',
  quantity: 3,
  expiryDate: DateTime(2022, 01, 8),     
),
MoveItem(
  shelf: A04,
  itemName: 'Meatball',
  quantity: 3,
  expiryDate: DateTime(2022, 02, 8),     
),
MoveItem(
  shelf: A05,
  itemName: 'Meatball',
  quantity: 3,
  expiryDate: DateTime(2022, 02, 8),      
),];
```

How do I group the list by itemName AND expiryDate?

EDIT:

Using usual ListView.builder and intl package like this:

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) =>                      
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          _items[i].itemName,
                        ),
                        Text(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                            .format(_items[i].expiryDate)),
                        Text(
                          _items[i].quantity.toString(),
                        )]),
```

I would get this:

```
Dumpling    2021-12-8   3
Dumpling    2021-12-8   3
Dumpling    2022-01-8   3
Meatball    2022-02-8   3
Meatball    2022-02-8   3
```

The outcome I need:

```
Dumpling    2021-12-8   6
Dumpling    2022-01-8   3
Meatball    2022-02-8   6
```

I also need to pass the data of each group down the widget tree.

Using collection package, I could only group them by itemName OR expiryDate.

Comment: You can try use gridView builder https://medium.com/@vignesh_prakash/flutter-listview-and-gridview-with-tabbar-221516518c75

Comment: How to get the GridView display the outcome I'm looking for? I have 5 MoveItems, and need to group them according to the itemName AND expiryDate values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You can group them using the item name and the date since these values you want to be the same:

```
  Map<String, MoveItem> groups = {};

  for (MoveItem item in _items) {
    String convertedDateTime =
        "${item.expiryDate.year.toString()}-${item.expiryDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${item.expiryDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
    if (groups[item.itemName + ' ' + convertedDateTime] == null)
      groups[item.itemName + ' ' + convertedDateTime] = MoveItem(
        expiryDate: item.expiryDate,
        quantity: item.quantity,
        itemName: item.itemName,
      );
    else
      groups[item.itemName + ' ' + convertedDateTime].quantity += item.quantity;
  }
```

Output:

```
{
   Dumpling 2021-12-08:Dumpling - 2021-12-08 6,
   Dumpling 2022-01-08:Dumpling - 2022-01-08 3,
   Meatball 2022-02-08:Meatball - 2022-02-08 6
}
```

My model:

```
class MoveItem {
  String itemName;
  int quantity;
  DateTime expiryDate;
  MoveItem({this.itemName, this.quantity, this.expiryDate});

  @override
  String toString() {
    String convertedDateTime =
        "${expiryDate.year.toString()}-${expiryDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${expiryDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
    return itemName + ' - ' + convertedDateTime + ' ' + quantity.toString();
  }
}
```

EDIT:

To use in a ListView.builder, it's easier to use a list for that:

```
  List<MoveItem> groups = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; i++) {
    bool groupExists = false;
    for (MoveItem group in groups) {
      if (group.itemName == _items[i].itemName &&
          group.expiryDate == _items[i].expiryDate) {
        group.quantity += _items[i].quantity;
        groupExists = true;
      }
    }
    if (!groupExists) {
      groups.add(_items[i]);
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
[Dumpling - 2021-12-08 6, Dumpling - 2022-01-08 3, Meatball - 2022-02-08 6]
```

Using it in a ListView:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: groups.length,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Text(
        groups[i].itemName,
      ),
      Text(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
          .format(groups[i].expiryDate)),
      Text(
        groups[i].quantity.toString(),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I actually don't mind using Dart intl package to format the date.
My problem is, I need to pass the values of each group to the next screen. Is there a way to do that using your answer?
I've edited the original question to be clear.

Comment: @BillyJoseph just updated my answer, I hope it works now ;)

Comment: Ah OK, that makes it easier for me to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. Before I had only `.groupListsBy((e) => e.id)`, but now i also had to group with multiple values (id and time). So this helped me out. Sad that I can't add more values to groupListBy, that would have saved me few hours of searching.